# How to bind image in angularjs from firebase storage

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

How to show image in angularjs view from Firebase Storage reference? 
I can print url in console but can't access in view.

Service Code

```
function getImageUrl(image) {
        var url;
        var pathReference = firebaseDataService.images.child(image);
        return pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
           return url;                
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle any errors
        });         
    }
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.getImageUrl = function(image) {
var imageUrl;
    var imageUrl = Service.getImageUrl(image).then(function(url) {  
          imageUrl = url;
          console.log(url);
          return imageUrl;
    });
   return imageUrl;
}
```

View

```
 <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <img src="{{getImageUrl(category.image)}}">
 </div>
```

Comment: you should be retrieving the images url by the time you retrieve the categories and store them in a diferent obj. `<img src="{{images.categoryId}}">`

Comment: I am getting categories in seperate service method and than in ng-repeat i am calling storage service to get image url.

Comment: Let me see the method that retrieves the categories.

Comment: What comes in `console.log(url);`?

Comment: @AtulSirpal Let me know if you made any progress or if you still have any doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you retrieve your categories you can loop over the categories and retrieve each image, store it in a diferent scope object and use it in your view.

```
$scope.images = {};

categoriesSnapshot.forEach(function(category){
    Service.getImageUrl(category.val().image).then(function(url) {  
          $scope.images[category.key] = url;
    }); 
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in categories">
    <img src="{{images[key]}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution,I found images were not visible due to It was due to digest cycle and I resolved by using  $scope.$apply().

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

```
<img ng-src="{{getImageUrl(category.image)}}">
```

Comment: Still not working,I am not sure but i think this is due to promise