# Images from firebase storage in ngrepeat won't show

Tags: angularjs, firebase-storage

I am trying to download images from firebase storage into an ng-repeat. The syntax i am using i got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523515/function-that-returns-download-url-from-firebase-storage) and also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312561/how-to-bind-image-in-angularjs-from-firebase-storage).

```
 .controller('tryCtrl',  function($scope,$firebaseStorage,$firebaseArray){
   $scope.user = 'OPD0wmF3syajsD94ANBBEQgzWPz2';
   const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
   const ref = rootRef.child('UserData' + '/' + $scope.user);
   var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
   $scope.listOFProducts = list;



 $scope.getImageUrl = function(Image){
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref($rootScope.user + '/' + Image);
    var storage = $firebaseStorage(storageRef);

  return storage.$getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
       $scope.url = url;
       console.log($scope.url);
      return url;
    })
   };

   })
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="items in details.Products">
         <div class="spacer" ng-init=""></div>

          <a class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="open(items)">

              <img ng-src="{{getImageUrl(items.Image)}}" class="img-responsive">
          </a>

              <p>{{items.Price}}</p>  
        </div>
<img ng-src="{{url}}">
```

My challenge is that the returned url does not display any image. The url attached to scope however displays all the image; changing from one image to another within about a second of each image. Conosole.log($scope.url) shows the download url constantly changing. I will be grateful if someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: The `getImageUrl` function returns a promise, not a URL. It is unwise to have Angular Expressons invoke asynchronous APIs. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly bind the url, since you have the image in the scope variable,

```
<img ng-src="url" class="img-responsive">
```